# Adding detectable Nullable values to CsvHelper

Tags: string, nullable, csvhelper

I was wondering if CsvHelper by Josh Close has anything in the configuration I am missing to translate values to null. I am a huge fan of this library, but I always thought there should be some sort of configuration to let it know what values represent NULL in your file. An example would be a column with the value "NA", "EMPTY", "NULL", etc. I am sure I could create my own TypeConverter, but I was hoping there would be an easier option to set somewhere in a config as this tends to be fairly common with files I encounter.

Is there a configuration setting to do this relatively easily?

I found the TypeConversion in the CsvHelper.TypeConversion namespace but am not sure where to apply something like this or an example of the correct usage:

```cs
new NullableConverter(typeof(string)).ConvertFromString(new TypeConverterOptions(), "NA")
```

I am also using the latest version 2.2.2

Thank you!

Comment: Currently you will need to create a custom converter like @JNYRanger said and extend `NullableConverter`. Having the ability to set a configuration of other values that evaluate to `null` seems like a handy feature, and I'm surprised this hasn't come up before. I'll add it as a new feature request.

Comment: @JoshClose, Even a "PrepareData" event on the Map would work, ie Map(m => m.Prop).Prepare = func<instring,outstring>, we can sorta do this with convertusing, but that completely overrides the automap

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CsvHelper can absolutely handle nullable types.  You do not need to roll your own TypeConverter if a blank column is considered null. For my examples I am assuming you are using user-defined fluent mappings.

The first thing you need to do is construct a `CsvHelper.TypeConverter` object for your Nullable types.  Note that I'm going to use `int` since strings allow null values by default.

```cs
public class MyClassMap : CsvClassMap<MyClass>
{
     public override CreateMap()
     {
          CsvHelper.TypeConversion.NullableConverter intNullableConverter = new CsvHelper.TypeConversion.NullableConverter(typeof(int?));

          Map(m => m.number).Index(2).TypeConverter(intNullableConverter);
      }
 }
```

Next is setting the attribute on your CsvReader object to allow blank columns & auto-trim your fields.  Personally like to do this by creating a `CsvConfiguration` object with all of my settings prior to constructing my `CsvReader` object.

```cs
CsvConfiguration csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration();
csvConfig.RegisterClassMap<MyClassMap>();
csvConfig.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
csvConfig.TrimFields = true;
```

Then you can call `myReader = new CsvReader(stream, csvConfig)` to build the `CsvReader` object.

IF you need to have defined values for null such as `"NA" == null` then you will need to roll your own `CsvHelper.TypeConversion` class.  I recommend that you extend the `NullableConverter` class to do this and override both the constructor and `ConvertFromString` method.  Using blank values as null is really your best bet though.

Answer (score 39):

I think some time in the last seven years and thirteen versions since this question was asked the options for doing this without a custom type map class expanded, e.g.:

```cs
csvReader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<string>().NullValues.Add("NULL");
csvReader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<DateTime?>().NullValues.AddRange(new[] { "NULL", "0" });
csvReader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<int?>().NullValues.Add("NULL");
csvReader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<bool>().BooleanFalseValues.Add("0");
csvReader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<bool>().BooleanTrueValues.Add("1");
```

Comment: For someone new to CsvHelper in 2021 (v22.1.2), the `TypeConverterOptionsCache` is no longer on the `Configuration` property.  It is now: `csvReader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<>`.  Not sure when it changed but thought I'd put it out there :)

Comment: Thanks S. Rasmussen, I verified and updated the post

Answer (score 4):

I used "ConvertUsing"...

```cs
public class RecordMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<Record>
{
    public RecordMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
        Map(m => m.TransactionDate).ConvertUsing( NullDateTimeParser );
        Map(m => m.DepositDate).ConvertUsing( NullDateTimeParser );
    }

    public DateTime? NullDateTimeParser(IReaderRow row)
    {
        //"CurrentIndex" is a bit of a misnomer here - it's the index of the LAST GetField call so we need to +1
        //https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1168

        var rawValue = row.GetField(row.Context.CurrentIndex+1);

        if (rawValue == "NULL")
            return null;
        else
            return DateTime.Parse(rawValue);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's now a built in way to handle this through adding an attribute on properties directly. The `NullValuesAttribute` takes a list of strings that will be mapped as null:

```
    [NullValues("NULL", "0001/01/01")]
    public DateTime? BoardDate { get; init; }
```